# Angular 9 Universal ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to setup SSR on angular 9 project with some third party librairies without success.

Below the error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at ./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js (main.js:295050:32)
at Object../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js (main.js:295052:3)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20:30)
at Object../node_modules/intl-tel-input/index.js (main.js:296381:18)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20:30)
at Module../node_modules/intl-tel-input-ng/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/intl-tel-input-ng.js (main.js:294832:72)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20:30)
    at Object.. main.js:463107:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20:30)
    at Object.. main.js:462977:33)
A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:50362
```

I don't have access to window object on the server side, it's normal, so to avoid this error I'm checking the platform and using conditional logic in the components that need intl-tel-input lib ...without success.

How can I fix window, navigator, document error while SSR  ?

below package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "dz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {

    "compile:server_bak": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:ssr_bak": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "serve:ssr_bak": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles_bak": "npm run build-prod && ng run dz:server:production",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run dz:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run dz:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run dz:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^9.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.0-next.5",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.0.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^8.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.11.1",
    "@smip/ngx-materialize": "^0.3.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^13.0.2",
    "@trilon/ng-universal": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.141",
    "acorn": "^7.1.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.27.9",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.9.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.3.0",
    "angular2-image-upload": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "calendar-utils": "0.7.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "cors": "~2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "domino": "^2.1.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-http-proxy": "^1.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
    "gzip-all": "^1.0.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "16.0.10",
    "intl-tel-input-ng": "0.1.0",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "mock-browser": "^0.92.14",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-sticky-kit": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "5.0.0",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-quicklink": "^0.2.0",
    "ngx-scrollspy": "^1.2.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "positioning": "1.4.0",
    "preboot": "^7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.7.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "workbox-sw": "^4.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.10.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~6.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.5",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "2mb",
      "maximumError": "5mb"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this?  I have the problem as well.   Wasn't an issue in Angular 8 even with SSR.

Answer (score 2):

If you have mutiple components where you need window to be used. There is one more way to fix this error, where you need not to import or install any third party package.

Reason of this error is, while excuting or parsing the code at node server, window is not defined. So, to avoid that we can put if condition like this `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))`  which will be executed only when the script is running at browser level

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'space-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onActivate() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

This is for the places where you will be using `window` directly. But what if any third party angular package is using `window` that you aren't aware of. To prevent errors from those cases. We need to add a piece of code in server.ts

```
const path = require('path');
const domino = require('domino');
const templateA = fs.readFileSync(path.join('dist/browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
// Express server
export const app = express();
```

But make sure the position of `export const app = express()` is correct

Comment: This gives error  "Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable "

Answer (score 2):

I declared this at the top of my `server.ts` file and it worked

```
(global as {window: unknown}).window = global;
```

Comment: This won't work if the problem is that the library/code that access window it's accessing a property. Still fails for `window.getComputedStyle()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using window object in this way

in .ts file import it

```
import { WINDOW } from '@ng-toolkit/universal';
```

then in constructor inject it

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) public window: Window) {

}
```

and use it inside any function like below

```
getBlogs() {
    this.blogsService.getBlogs().subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.message === 'success') {
        this.blogs = res.data.blogs;
        this.window.scroll(0, 0);
      } else {
        console.log('No blogs');
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I dont want to directly use Window Object, its needed inside third party lib(intl-tel-input-ng).

Comment: I know its quite late but for others. For window in third party packages, you can add a piece of code in your server.ts which i have given above.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 Angular SSR projects which the same config, but one of them faced an issue because have node_modules use `window` but not validate.

**The solution:**

- Find in the `main.js` which lib make an error, after that search how to pass it.
- For me, I just upgrade the Nodejs version from 10.x to 14.x the problem was resolve.