# Angualr 14 ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to use angular universal in my project. Affter i added it I see error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I am not using `window` in my project, but maybe it uses in thirty part library. How to solve this problem?

I already saw simular qustion: [Angular 9 Universal ReferenceError: window is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188777/angular-9-universal-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined) its answer doesn't help.

Comment: Try checking the exception call stack to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: I found library witch useses windows web-audio-daw. Ok I can replace by another. But there is a lot of libraries witch useses window, and not every has alternative. What need to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the code with a check using `isPlatformServer`

```
export class ArtistShowComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    this.isServerSide = isPlatformServer(platformId);
  }

  isServerSide: boolean;

  doSomething() {
    // If the issue is in typescript
    if (this.isServerSide) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If the issue is in a third-party angular component / HTML:

```
<!-- Remove the component from the DOM -->
<ng-carousel *ngIf="!isServerSide"></div>
```